# React Native DrawerLayout: animating child results in infinite recursion

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Expo's `GestureHandler.DrawerLayout` supports animating the contents of the drawer based on an `AnimatedInterpolation` provided to the `renderNavigationView` method. However, I wanted to animate the main view rather than the drawer, so in my `renderNavigationView` method, I grabbed the value and put into my component's state, and then I tried to use it in my component's `render` method.

Here is a minimal sample project to show what I mean:

https://github.com/brettdh/drawer-resize-child

And here is the main `App` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { GestureHandler } from 'expo';

const { DrawerLayout } = GestureHandler;

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      progressValue: null,
    };
  }

  getAnimatedStyles() {
    const margin =
      this.state.progressValue
        ? this.state.progressValue.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 1],
          outputRange: [0, 30],
        })
        : 0;
    return {
      paddingVertical: margin,
    }
  }

  renderDrawer(progressValue) {
    if (!this.state.progressValue) {
      this.setState({ progressValue });
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.drawer}>
        <Text>Drawer content</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <DrawerLayout
        ref={drawer => {this.drawer = drawer;}}
        renderNavigationView={(pv) => this.renderDrawer(pv)}
        drawerWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.75}
        drawerType="back"
        overlayColor="#00000000"
      >
        <View style={[styles.container, this.getAnimatedStyles()]}>
          <Button onPress={() => this.drawer.openDrawer()} title="Open drawer"/>
        </View>
      </DrawerLayout>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  drawer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#F95A570C',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

When I run this project (`yarn && yarn start`, press `i`), I get this in the iOS Simulator:

```
non-std C++ exception

ABI26_0_0RCTFatal
-[ABI26_0_0RCTCxxBridge handleError:]
__43-[ABI26_0_0RCTCxxBridge _initializeBridge:]_block_invoke
facebook::ReactABI26_0_0::ABI26_0_0RCTMessageThread::tryFunc(std::__1::function<void ()> const&)
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
__CFRunLoopDoBlocks
__CFRunLoopRun
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
+[ABI26_0_0RCTCxxBridge runRunLoop]
__NSThread__start__
_pthread_body
_pthread_body
thread_start
```

and this in React Native Debugger:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

This error is located at:
    in RCTView (at View.js:78)
    in View (at App.js:49)
    in RCTView (at View.js:78)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:147)
    in AnimatedComponent (at DrawerLayout.js:378)
    in RCTView (at View.js:78)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:147)
    in AnimatedComponent (at DrawerLayout.js:377)
    in Handler (at DrawerLayout.js:425)
    in DrawerLayout (at App.js:42)
    in App (at registerRootComponent.js:35)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at registerRootComponent.js:34)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:78)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
    in RCTView (at View.js:78)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
```

These errors preceded the one that blew up my app:

```
Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within 
`render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure 
function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but
can be moved to `componentWillMount`.
```

(I'd like to avoid that `setState` during `render()`, but I'm not sure how. That might be a react-native-gesture-handler feature request, to have `DrawerLayout` inject a `progressValue` prop into its child components.)

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `paddingVertical` supplied to `View`.
Bad object: {
  "flex": 1,
  "backgroundColor": "#fff",
  "alignItems": "center",
  "justifyContent": "center",
  "paddingVertical": 0
}
    in View (at App.js:49)
    in App (at registerRootComponent.js:35)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at registerRootComponent.js:34)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:78)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
    in RCTView (at View.js:78)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
```

Aside: I feel like this also merits a bug report, but I can't tell if it's an issue with React Native, Expo, or react-native-gesture-handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Animated` from React-Native. Change `View` to `Animated.View`. Use the callback from the `Animated.timing` function to set your state.

Comment: `DrawerLayout` is already using `Animated` - specifically, `Animated.Interpolation`. The input data source for that interpolation is internal to `DrawerLayout`.

However - are you saying that *any* `Animated.Value` needs to be consumed by an `Animated.View`? That kind of makes sense, though I must have missed it in the documentation. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Yes, any Animated.Value needs to be consumed by an Animated.View.

Comment: Unfortunately `Animated.View` doesn't support the `paddingVertical` style prop that I'm using, so now I'm looking into `LayoutAnimation` to get this working. I think the fact that I'm trying to call `setState` inside `render` is causing me problems there, though.

When I was using native animations, I saw an explicit error message saying that `paddingVertical` was not supported. However, when I switched this to specify `useNativeDriver: false` (indirectly, via `DrawerLayout`'s `useNativeAnimations` prop), I got no error message (and no animation). Is this what you'd expect?

Comment: There's too much to type here, but linked below is a button which used Animated.Interpolate to change the background. You can try using it as a guide: https://gist.github.com/lucas1richard/84f9132468717ca04cee145280f8248c

Comment: Thanks for the pointers here - I finally cracked it (just pushed a new version). I think it was actually working as soon as I specified `useNativeAnimations={false}` on the `DrawerLayout`; I just wasn't seeing the animation because i had set `backgroundColor` on the wrong `View`. I ended up using a `setTimeout` hack to get the setState call out of `render` - which feels so very wrong, but I'm not sure what else to do in this case, other than the aforementioned feature request for the `DrawerLayout` API.